# Ubuntu 17.04 to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and Dual Boot Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade, 18.04

I am new to the Linux community and ended up installing 17.04 a while back ago. However, now I really regret that.

I need to have both Windows 10 and want to upgrade to 18.04 LTS as I hear it's available today. Can you please provide me a step by step guide on doing this? I don't have a great understanding of Linux systems yet, so I would appreciate a guide in layman's terms.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS [is released](http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/). So we should stop closing questions as off-topic.

Comment: Note that, in spite of being listed last in the duplicate banner, the main question you'll want to look at for this is [**How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) That's what actually shows you how to upgrade from an EOL release whose *own* repositories have been moved over to the `old-releases` server.